# Find group of N similar numbers in group of N+M numbers

Tags: sql, algorithm

I'm trying to find similar values from an array -not just one, but a group of them, while the sum of their element-wise differences is to be the lowest possible value

EXAMPLE:

0
2
4
6
8
9
11
15
16
19

pick 5 numbers

RESULT:

4
6
8
9
11

or

2
4
6
8
9

Where the sum of the element-wise difference of both groups is 7.

The problem is I need to select such group of 1500 numbers from an array of 2927 numbers and I'm not sure if algorithm which takes groups of 0-1500 (indexes)numbers and sums the differences, then goes i+1 until it reaches the 1427-2927 group is effective (finally I would check the smallest sum and which group it belongs to).

Note, that numbers are sorted (doesn't matter if ASC or DESC) and I'm trying to do that using PostgreSQL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is the difference 7? They are the same 4-group, with 2 added for the first, and 11 for the second. How did you end up with 11?

Comment: 11-9 = 2
9-8 = 1
8-6 = 2
6-4 =2

Whereas 2+2+1+2 = 7

Same for 

9-8 = 1
8-6 = 2
6-4 = 2
4-2 = 2

1+2+2+2=7

Comment: When you say "count of the difference," what do you mean? It doesn't sound like you mean a count, you seem to be using common words in nonstandard ways.

Comment: How is the data stored in SQL? With 2 fields: index, value?

Comment: Excuse me, not count but sum

Comment: data is stored as:

String (name of city)
Integer(area of the city)

I'm basicaly searching for 1500 cities with most similar areas out of 2927 cities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a3f63/18)

**PostgreSQL 9.3 Schema Setup**:

A small dataset of random data:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT,
  population INT
);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (  1, 12 );
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (  2, 11 );
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (  3, 14 );
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (  4,  6 );
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (  5,  7 );
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (  6,  7 );
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (  7,  1 );
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (  8, 15 );
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (  9, 14 );
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ( 10, 14 );
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ( 11, 15 );
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ( 12, 12 );
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ( 13, 11 );
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ( 14,  3 );
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ( 15,  8 );
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ( 16,  1 );
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ( 17,  1 );
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ( 18,  2 );
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ( 19,  3 );
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ( 20,  5 );
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH ordered_sums AS (
  SELECT ID,
         POPULATION,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY POPULATION ) AS RN,
         POPULATION - LAG(POPULATION,4) OVER ( ORDER BY POPULATION ) AS DIFFERENCE
  FROM   test
), minimum_rn AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT FIRST_VALUE( RN ) OVER wnd AS optimal_rn
  FROM   ordered_sums
  WINDOW wnd AS ( ORDER BY DIFFERENCE )
)
SELECT ID,
       POPULATION
FROM   ordered_sums o
       INNER JOIN
       minimum_rn m
       ON ( o.RN BETWEEN m.OPTIMAL_RN - 4 AND m.OPTIMAL_RN )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a3f63/18/0)**:

```
| id | population |
|----|------------|
| 10 |         14 |
|  9 |         14 |
|  3 |         14 |
| 11 |         15 |
|  8 |         15 |
```

The query above will select `5` rows - to change it to select `N` rows then change the `4`s in the `LAG` function and in the last line to `N-1`.

Comment: I'm actually working in QGIS database (no idea what version of SQL it uses) and none of posted seem to work so far. Either it's a problem of SQL or the problem is somewhere between the chair and computer.

But I really appreciate the response.

Comment: EDIT : I guess it's Postgres

Comment: @Whatever - Edited to give PostgreSQL solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the list is `a[1]`, `a[2]`, ..., `a[N+M]`.

1. Calculate the minimal value of `a[i+M-1]-a[i]` for `i=1` to `N+1`.
2. The value(s) of `i` for which the minimal value is reached are the first indices of `M` consecutive numbers in which the sum of the element-wise difference is minimal.

One key observation to understand this algorithm is that the "sum of the element-wise differences" of a sequence of sorted integers is simply the difference between the first and last element. E.g. for `4 6 8 9 11` it is `11-4=7`.

Comment: If you were to do a row_number() function on the data, sorting by size, you could then self-join the data set on id=id+1499 and look at the differences of the two sizes. This new result could then be sorted ascending by difference.

Comment: I'll say this bluntly - I never did a for loop in SQL and I'm not sure if I will ever be able to solve this, even 'tho now I understand the algorithm! :) 

Could you post the SQL solution? (Table has 2 collumns - City and area and you can add any number of collumns, if needed)

Answer (score 0):

This solution should work. Row_number() to get the order. self-Join on +1499, then order by the difference of sizes in the pair.

```
DECLARE @cities TABLE (
    city VARCHAR(512)
    ,size INT
    ,rownum INT
    )

INSERT INTO @cities
SELECT *
    ,row_number() OVER (
        ORDER BY size
        ) rownum
FROM 
    rawdata

SELECT *
    ,d.size - c.size difference
FROM @cities c
INNER JOIN @cities d ON c.rownum + 1499 = d.rownum
WHERE c.rownum <=2927-1499
ORDER BY d.size - c.size
```